# Wii Nunchuk as an IR wireless remote

Tags: bluetooth, remote

I am building a smart Mirror and I need to find a way to interface a Wii Nunchuk, with the 'c' button removed and replaced with an IR LED to track the cursor and a small Arduino board to capure the joystick movement and the 'z' button presses and then a Bluetooth module that takes the information from the Arduino and send it to the Raspberry Pi.

To sum it up, here are the questions...

- how do I set up the Arduino and the Bluetooth module to capture the button presses and the joystick state from the Nunchuk
- how do I set up the Raspberry Pi to receive the data from the Bluetooth module and set up double click button 'z' to left click and hold 'z' to right click
- how do I set up the webcam/PiCam to pick up the IR LED and then replace the co-ordinates of the LED with the cursor co-ordinated
- if i were to use a PiCam, do I use the PiCam Noir or the normal one
- is there a way to set up the Bluetooth module to only connect to the Raspberry Pi and not to any other device

If you don't know what a Wii Nunchuk looks like, here are some pictures...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see that you have already asked a similar question some days ago. But no-one bothered to answer it. I don't think this will be much different than your other question. Here is what you need to do get your question answered: Try to to solve your own problem **yourself** first. If you get **stuck**: - Come here. - Present what you tried. - Explain what you have researched. - Explain what alternatives might work. Try to be specific. Try  to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @MadMike yeah, I have yet to delete that question due to the fact that I feel that this question is much better structured and more concise.